# Issue when renaming multiple column names in pandas by extracting a element in tuple as string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Now I am working with a dataframe, with the column as follows:

```
(Column A, Response) (Column B, Response) (Column C, Response) (Unknown, Item 1) (Unknown, Item 2) ...
  1001                1001                 1001                 1001             1001
  1002                1002                 1002                 1002             1002
  ...
```

For the first 3 columns, i don't need the 'Response' in the tuple and what I want to do is to delete the second part of the tuple in column 1-3, return the first part as a string and rename the column. For the columns from column 4 onwards, it's another way round so that I do not want to apply the same rules from there.

I tried the following:

```
for i in range(0,3): 
    print(df.column[i][0])
    df.rename({df.columns[i]: df.columns[i][0]}, inplace=True)
```

for the print, I got the right result:

```
Column A
Column B
Column C
```

However, when I printed out the columns in the df after the command, it showed the same as before.

```
MultiIndex([(         'Column A', ...),
            (         'Column B', ...),
            (         'Column C', ...)],
           )
```

What was the problem here? 
And at the same time if I want to convert the output to string, can I also do it in df.rename command or shd I do it somewhere afterwards?

Meanwhile, when I tried the following:

```
 for i in range(0,3): 
        print(df.column[i][0])
        df = df.rename({df.columns[i]: df.columns[i][0]}, inplace=True)
```

It returns AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'columns'

Why would it be?
Thank you for your help!

---

Additional information:
The table before was in multilevel index, and what I did was to flatten the multilevel index table with the command

```
df.columns.to_flat_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a MultiIndex here, which cannot be processed as an Index of tuple values. You must use the MultiIndex method `get_level_values` to extract one level:

```
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
```

Specifically, rename is applied separately on the labels of each level which is not what you want here.

Comment: Thanks! I applied the method that you mentioned, and now the output is 

Index(['Column A', 'Response'), ('Column B', 'Response') ...] ) .

If rename is not the way that I shd choose, then how shd I proceed?